# Simple Javascript to change style doesnt work

Tags: javascript, css

Here is a little code sample:

```
var moving_nav = document.getElementById("moving_nav");
var logo = document.getElementById("logo");

setInterval(function(){ 
    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if ( scrolled >= 100) {
        moving_nav.style.position = "fixed";
        moving_nav.style.top = "0";
        logo.style.width:"60px";
        logo.style.height:"60px";
    } 
    else {
        moving_nav.style.position = "absolute";
        moving_nav.style.top = "100px";
        logo.style.width:"120px";
        logo.style.height:"120px";
    }
}, 10);
```

It was meant to make my menu sticky when you scroll over it. That worked perfectly fine :). But then I wanted my logo to change aswell. And that's were it stopped working. (Just after I included the lines in which "logo" appears.)

Browser Console says there is a missing ";" in line 9 (first "width") but I don't know where exactly it belongs. I tried solving the problem by not using a var but actually using getElementById every time. Didn't work out for me. Also I tried commenting out the lines where I style my logo and the rest worked perfectly. I just can't find the problem :( Please help!

PS: Also don't be mad at me if you think that's too easy. I'm a greenhorn when it comes to JS. Furthermore I'm not a native speaker so please excuse my (missing) english skills ;)

Thanks, Diavo

Comment: Why do you use `=` in one case and `:` in another? Don't you think that operations are similar and there should be one syntax for them all?

Comment: Thanks :)
I knew it was something simple. Sometimes you just don't see the most obvious things. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any style property you have to use `=` only when applying using js.
When using css you have to use :

```
if ( scrolled >= 100) {
    moving_nav.style.position = "fixed";
    moving_nav.style.top = "0";
    logo.style.width = "60px";
    logo.style.height = "60px";
} 
else {
    moving_nav.style.position = "absolute";
    moving_nav.style.top = "100px";
    logo.style.width = "120px";
    logo.style.height = "120px";
}
```

Replaced *`:`* with *`=`*

Comment: Whooops! That's quite embarrassing. Thanks for the friendly answer :) You never find the most obvious things :D

Comment: You are Welcome @Diavo

Answer (score 1):

```
    logo.style.width="60px";
    logo.style.height="60px";
```

instead of

```
    logo.style.width:"60px";
    logo.style.height:"60px";
```

Other one as well.

Comment: Thanks :) I knew it was something simple. Sometimes you just don't see the most obvious things. :D

Answer (score 1):

You used `:` instead `=`.We use `:` in **css**

```
var moving_nav = document.getElementById("moving_nav");
    var logo = document.getElementById("logo");

    setInterval(function(){ 
        var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if ( scrolled >= 100) {
            moving_nav.style.position = "fixed";
            moving_nav.style.top = "0";
            logo.style.width="60px";
            logo.style.height="60px";
        } 
        else {
            moving_nav.style.position = "absolute";
            moving_nav.style.top = "100px";
            logo.style.width="120px";
            logo.style.height="120px";
        }
    }, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks :) I knew it was something simple. Sometimes you just don't see the most obvious things. :D